# Converting to latest swift syntax broke app

Tags: xcode

When I opened XCode it asked me to convert to latest swift syntax and I pressed "Convert". I suddenly had 70+ errors while the app used to work perfectly.. I already tried the clean option but the errors still show up. How can I fix this? Is there a way to restore it?

Comment: Restore with version control. But if you go through the errors you should be able to fix them.

Comment: In source control I can't find any recent update.. I did archive and submit them to itunes connect though..